# Difference amplifier schematic

Tags: amplifier

[image: difference amplifier]

I am trying to get this difference amplifier working, but it doesn't seem to be outputting what I want it to output.

$$
V_1 = V_{in}\qquad
V_2 = -0.5\mathrm{V}\qquad
R_f=R_i, \quad A=1
$$

I want the output to always be \$V_{in}+0.5\mathrm{V}\$. So, 
$$
V_o = \dfrac{R_f}{R_i}\cdot (V_{in}-(-0.5))
$$

What to do?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Whether my circuit is incorrect, because the output isn't giving me 5-(-0.5)*1 = 5.5v but rather 380mV. I have no idea why.

Comment: I'm not sure about your circuit.  But you have it supplied with 0 to 10 V and are then applying a -0.5V signal... below the supply rails.  This is verboten.  Try making the ground on the M9,8,7 sources equal to -5V (or something)  You may have to change some other "grounds" too.  (the current source??)

Answer (score 1):

George is right: your amplifier doesn't work because your input (-0.5 V) is outside the acceptable input range.

In order for the amplifier to work, the NMOS in the pull-down section (M3N, M4P and M7) must be ON and saturated. Therefore the inputs must be at least \$V_{GSon} + V_{DSsat}\$, or about 0.9 V (very indicatively, depends on the devices).

So you either have to use a negative supply or change the input range. Note that using a differential amplifier with negative output may not be the smartest way to shift your signal up by 0.5 V. One thing to look for are *level shifters*.